# What should be done about users who answer too much?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes a user may post too many answers, or “absurd” amount sometimes, relatively speaking. But if said user does it on a daily basis?

A few of them may be good, but the vast majority of their answers are being mod deleted, are just comments, don’t answer the question, or don’t even try/attempt to be an answer. It seems to swamp the site.

What, if anything, should be done about such users? While they are not technically doing anything wrong, as far as I know, is there anything to be done?

Comment: At Earth Sciences when I participated on the site we had a user with lots of downvoted answers. He started to receive negatives in mass when we asked him for sources of their arguments and answered it was experience knowledge. It is mod decision. At Earth Science he continues answering 50% of questions, at physics exchange his acount was frozen, suspended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave a comment on one of their posts, linking to the [Help Center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). That's rather easy to type: just type `[answer]` and it will automatically render into a link:

> [How to Answer](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer)

That's just generic advice; the user might be helped more if you point out some specific details that can be improved.

If the answer warrants it, downvote it and/or flag it as very low quality; the reviewers in the Low Quality Posts review queue will take care of it. If the user continues with this behaviour, despite warnings from the community and/or moderators, they will run into an automatic answer ban, as described here: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/295232)